# How to get react working with Bootstrap 4 popovers

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am currently using Draftjs to decorate some key words, this turns them into spans. Within my span i'd like to use the Bootstrap 4 popover functionality. I have added a simple line and it did not work, the libraries etc are all added.

```
handleClick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
    alert(e.target);
};

ColorComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <span onClick={this.handleClick} style={this.styles.word}>{props.children}</span>
  );
};
```

On click i want to be able to see a popover appear like shown here on the bootstrap 4 page. I've included the links below. I dont want to use independent libraries, i want to code this directly and avoid having to use a plugin

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/popovers/

Comment: There are react libraries that help you with this. One of them is [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) and there are many topics here on SO for the [tag:react-bootstrap] tag.

Comment: I think you missed up the data-toggle attribute. Also the click handler must contain $('#element').popover('show')

Comment: React-bootstrap uses bootstrap 3 if i'm not mistaken

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the `data-toggle`, `title` and `data-content` attributes, then initialize the popover by calling the `popover()` method on the element.

See this answer for explanation and example code for a React, Typescript, Webpack stack: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46801561/924597